# How to check out a CodeCommit repo from within Codebuild?

Tags: git, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I have an AWS CodePipeline that is attached to a codecommit repo "A".  As part of the build process, I want to generate some artifacts from repo "A" and commit them to codecommit repo "B".  I have tried including

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoB
```

in the buildspec but I get this error in CodeBuild:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com': No such device or address

[Container] 2022/04/27 22:26:42 Command did not exit successfully git clone https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoB exit status 128
```

It seems like it does not have credentials. I have also tried including the username and password in the git command like this `git clone https://codepipelineuser-at-***:***@git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoB`  and got this error:

```
[Container] 2022/04/27 21:33:45 Command did not exit successfully git clone git clone https://codepipelineuser-at-***:***@git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoB exit status 129
[Container] 2022/04/27 21:33:45 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/04/27 21:33:45 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: git clone git clone https://codepipelineuser-at-123542344134:***@git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/AmplifySpec-Kotlin. Reason: exit status 129
```

(I know you should never check in a password but I just did it as a test and reset the password afterwards, and the repo is empty.  If that had worked I would have stored the password in Parameter Store).

How do I specify the credentials of my CodeCommit repo so I can check it out within CodeBuild?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to code commit in 2 ways
either create HTTP access on the IAM user, and use the username/password that u get from the generation of the access.

or you can use the accessKey+secretAccessKey but, its a bit complicated you need to use Signature V4 on your secretAccessKey